# How can I replace .on ('ready') with a namespace, to ready () while maintaining the namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I replace .on ('ready') with a namespace, to ready () while maintaining the namespace? 
This is the code to be replaced:

```
$(document).on('ready.checkboxes.data-api', dataApiDomReadyHandler);
```

This is the code from the checkboxes.js v1.2.2 library, that runs on jquery 1.10.1. And my jQuery code is 3.3.1. The .on ('ready') function is deprecated and removed in version 3.0.0.